# My current insert statement is not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Im creating a gift form for users to input their values. However the forms used to be working but suddenly, after a day, it goes straight into invalid. I am not sure where it goes wrong. Please help me out. Here are my codes. I have already review it and it seems fine to me. This problem kept on occuring and I cant pinpoint whats the mistake. I think it is something to do with the dates. In the database, I have put the datatype as DATE.

**CreateGift.cshtml**

```
@*Create Gift Page*@
@model SignUp3.Models.Gift;
@section MoreScripts {
<script src="~/lib/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/lib/dtpicker/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/dtpicker/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/styles/createform.css">
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="center">
                <form id="createuser" asp-controller="Gift" asp-action="CreateGift"
                         method="post">
                  <h3>Create Gift</h3>
                  <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="description">Description:<span style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input asp-for="description" placeholder="Full Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span asp-validation-for="description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="vouchercode">Voucher Code:<span style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input asp-for="vouchercode" placeholder="Voucher Code" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span asp-validation-for="vouchercode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="amount">Voucher Amount:<span style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input asp-for="amount" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span asp-validation-for="amount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="quantity">Quantity:<span style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input asp-for="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span asp-validation-for="quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="activation_date">Activation Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input asp-for="activation_date" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
                       class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span asp-validation-for="activation_date" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" asp-for="expiry">Expiry Date:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input asp-for="expiry" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
                       class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <span asp-validation-for="expiry" class="text-danger"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-6">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>

        @if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
        {
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="alert alert-@ViewData["MsgType"]">
                        @Html.Raw(ViewData["Message"])
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </form>

</div>
```

**GiftController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SignUp3.Models;

namespace SignUp3.Controllers
{
  public class GiftController : Controller
  {
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult CreateGift()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateGift(Gift gift)
    {
        // TODO: L09 Task 5 - Write secure code to insert Users into database
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Invalid Input";
            ViewData["MsgType"] = "warning";
            return View("CreateGift");
        }
        else
        {

             
            string sql = @"INSERT INTO GiftVoucher (description,amount,vouchercode,quantity,activation_date,expiry)
            VALUES('{0}',{1},'{2}',{3},'{4}','{5}')";

            if (DBUtl.ExecSQL(sql, gift.description,gift.amount, gift.vouchercode,gift.quantity,gift.activation_date,gift.expiry) == 1)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Gift Sucessfully Added.";
                TempData["MsgType"] = "success";
                return RedirectToAction("ViewGift");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Invalid";
                ViewData["MsgType"] = "danger";
                return View("CreateGift");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's clear your issue is on this line `DBUtl.ExecSQL(sql, gift.description,gift.amount, gift.vouchercode,gift.quantity,gift.activation_date,gift.expiry) == 1`. What is being returned from `DBUtil.ExecSQL`? What does it mean when the result is not `1`? What other possible values could be returned and what would they mean?

Comment: What's the problem now? The Message `"Invalid Input"` didn't show? Have you debug to check the ModelState?

Comment: @mj1313 The problem is that when I click on the submit button after inputting all the values in the forms it does not return a success message but instead it goes into             "else
            {
                ViewData["Message"] = "Invalid";
                ViewData["MsgType"] = "danger";
                return View("CreateGift");
            }"

Comment: @iwanttopassmyfyp so the method `DBUtl.ExecSQL` doesn't return `1`,  what does the returned value mean, you should check it.

Comment: @mj1313 It returns the value of -1. Why is this the case? In normal insert statement, the return value should be 1 when the forms are filled in correctly.

Comment: @iwanttopassmyfyp I don't know which db you use, but I think the insert sql failed, have you check your database if this record is successfully insearted.

Comment: @mj1313    ohh just checked the insert statement failed. So how do I allow it to insert successfully?  i realised when I remove the attribute called gift.expiry, then the insert statement works

Comment: What‘s the type of expiry column in database table.

Comment: @mj1313 the type is DATE.     [activation_date] DATE          NULL,
    [expiry]          DATE          NULL,

Comment: The Type `date` should be ok for "YYYY-MM-DD", what's the value of `gift.expiry` you received.

Comment: @mj1313      The value I received was {17/12/2020 12:00:00 am}. The type is System.DateTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion failed when converting date from this string `17/12/2020 12:00:00 am`.

You should format the insert parameter to meet the datatype `date`

```
gift.expiry.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

This *looks* like it is a failed insert due to formatting. I don't know what `DBUtl` is here, but: it *seems* like you're using `string.Format` to build SQL, which is *fundamentally* a terrible idea, because of all of:

- SQL injection
- i18n/l10n (date/number formatting)
- handling of quotes etc in strings
- query plan cache reuse

Ultimately, the only *correct* way to perform this kind of query is with parameters, not string replacement. Since you're writing you own SQL here, you might find Dapper (freely available on NuGet) a good option here:

```cs
int ret = connection.Execute(@"
INSERT INTO GiftVoucher (description,amount,vouchercode,quantity,activation_date,expiry)
VALUES(@description,@amount,@vouchercode,@quantity,@activation_date,@expiry)", gift);
```

Dapper will look for likely members on `gift` and add the ones that are mentioned in the sql. Alternatively, an anon-type can be useful:

```cs
int ret = connection.Execute(@"
INSERT INTO GiftVoucher (description,amount,vouchercode,quantity,activation_date,expiry)
VALUES(@description,@amount,@vouchercode,@quantity,@activation_date,@expiry)",
    new { gift.description, /* etc */, gift.expiry });
```

(this second approach is useful when parameters come from different places)